# HTML 投稿画面と閲覧画面

Tags: html

HTMLで投稿画面と閲覧画面で分けるには投稿画面（管理画面）の方に鍵をかければいいんですか ？

自分の画面と一般の画面で分けたいんですが

追記

「管理者でログインした場合の画面と、一般ユーザでログインした場合の画面を分けたい」とおもっています

Comment: いただいた質問では何をやりたいのか明確ではない印象です。もう少し具体的な質問をしてみてください。例えばどういう登場人物がいてどういう動作をしてシステムがどういう振る舞いをするのか。

Comment: 「自分の画面」と「一般の画面」は、それぞれ誰のマシンに表示されるものなのですか？
投稿画面と閲覧画面で分けるというのは、どのような意味で分けるのですか？「HTMLの画面を２分割する」、「管理者でログインした場合の画面と、一般ユーザでログインした場合の画面を分ける」など、いろいろな可能性がありうると思いますが、質問者は具体的には何をしたいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

HTMLだけでその機能を行うことは難しいです。
「鍵」を保管する方法がHTMLにはないからですね。

シンプルな方法だとWebサーバを利用した[digest認証](http://e-words.jp/w/Digest%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC.html)を用いることができますが、
ディレクトリやファイルごとの権限になるので、複雑な権限を設定したい場合や同じファイルで権限で出し分けをしたいとなると、アプリケーションを利用した認証の方法をとります。

アプリケーション認証とは、
いわゆるIDとパスワードを用いた、ログインの実装とセッションを利用したページ遷移ですね。

Webアプリケーションの認証の概念や方法については
この回答では範囲が広すぎてふさわしくないかつサーバサイドの言語やフレームワークによって
説明の内容が変わってきますので省略させていただきます。

「○○ 認証」※○○は言語やフレームワーク等
で検索すればいくつか出てきます。ぜひ調査を尽くして改めて質問してみてください。